# Getting an error: Webdriver cannot be resolved to a type ,Chromedriver cannot be resolved to a type. Please suggest

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
package firstPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class FirstScript {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Selenium\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you get the error ? In IDE editor ? or in console while running this code ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to answer your question but I'm guessing you didn't add the JARs to the project.

Check out how to do that:

For [Eclipse](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/configure-eclipse-with-selenium-webdriver/)

For [IntelliJ](https://www.guru99.com/intellij-selenium-webdriver.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.